# How to get table from EXEC sp_executesql in @TempTable, within a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need some help

**My goal:**

I have a `@query` in a stored procedure which is working perfectly. Now I have to perform more operation on the returning table from `@query` execution within same stored procedure. e.g I have to add more columns in the returning table and add new data from more queries.

**My problem:**

I am not able to get returning table form (`EXEC sp_executesql`) into a variable (`@TempTable`). And one more problem is that the number of columns returning are not known (dynamic).

**Steps should be like this:**

1. Declare `TempTable`
2. TempTable = EXEC sq_executesql
3. Add new columns to `TempTable`
4. Fill more data

Kindly guide me

Comment: Add the queries in the question it is bit confusing

Comment: Actually I am looking for queries to do this task. Please check the Algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved using global temp tables like below :

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @Column NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @Column = 'YouColumnList' -- id,name etc. created by you dynamically.

IF( Object_id('tempdb..##IntermediateTable') IS NOT NULL )
    DROP TABLE ##IntermediateTable

SET @sql = '
SELECT ' + @Column + '
Into   ##IntermediateTable
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  id = 123
'

EXEC sp_executesql
  @sql

IF( Object_id('tempdb..#temptable') IS NOT NULL )
    DROP TABLE #temptable

SELECT *
INTO   #temptable
FROM   ##IntermediateTable

IF( Object_id('tempdb..##IntermediateTable') IS NOT NULL )
    DROP TABLE ##IntermediateTable

SELECT *
FROM   #temptable --resulting temptable to use. alter it or do whatever desired.
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Deepak Pawar. This solution will work for adding new columns so this is for step 3.
Can also please guide me for step 2 which is about getting table of unknown columns in some variable, so we can perform required operations?

Comment: In step 2 I am executing a pivot query

Comment: Could you please elaborate step 2 and 3 in question? Add some of your code what you have tried till now even if it is wrong. That will help us to understand what you actually want.